Hiding specific video controls in html video element
<MediaPlayer
                    playsInline={isMobile ? true : false}
                    onTimeUpdate={videoTimeUpdate}
                    className={
                      isMobile ? "d-block d-md-none quizVideo" : "d-none d-md-block quizVideo"
                    }
                    controls={true}
                    autoPlay={playing}
                    ref={videoRef}
                    src={
                      isMobile
                        ? videosMobile[currentVideo]
                        : videos[currentVideo]
                    }
                  >
                    <MediaProvider />
                  </MediaPlayer>

The above is the video element for a video and below is the css to hide certain controls in my video component.
.quizVideo video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline, 
.quizVideo video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
.quizVideo video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
.quizVideo video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display, 
.quizVideo video::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button,
.quizVideo video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
display: none;
}

The above method could hide the controls for android, but did not work for iOS (I was attempting to hide every control, except the sound control). I am using the default html video styles, not using any custom styles for the controls.
How can I hide specific video controls, for iOS too?

Any progress? If not, then try testing on a <video> element instead of <MediaPlayer>... Also test setting display: none for each single option, not just as a group of options pointing to one setting (because if one option in the group is wrong, then the whole group fails to get the setting of none)

I was using next.js, using the normal  was inefficient and caused issues in rendering video for the mobile and desktop version. I tried using reactplayer, but that was inefficient too. Hence why I switched to vidstack. It offers a lot of functionalities and is easily customizable.
